# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Having issues with Aync Praw

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was using normal Praw for my Discord bot, when I eventually started getting this message:

```
It appears that you are using PRAW in an asynchronous environment.
It is strongly recommended to use Async PRAW: https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io.
See https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/multiple_instances.html#discord-bots-and-asynchronous-environments for more info.
```

It doesn't give me any errors, but seemed important so I tried switching to Async Praw. I changed `import praw` to `import asyncpraw`, and `reddit = praw.Reddit()` to `reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit()`.

And now in my code where it says `memes_hot = memes.hot(limit = 100)`, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'hot'
```

Comment: memes was a coroutine
you need to await on it before using its  result

Comment: is ````hot````  defined within your code? because of the error message it looks like you didn't define it

Comment: Please show definition of `memes`

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've invluded that: `memes = reddit.subreddit("memes")`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `coroutine`, put `await` in front of it. 
 Try this: `await memes.hot(limit=100)`

Comment: This won't solve it. if `memes` is a coroutine, then memes.hot() will not exist.

Comment: Yeah I still get `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'hot'` :(

Comment: ok so since memes is reddit.subreddit("memes"), that should be the coroutine. Try putting `await` before reddit.subreddit

Comment: Okay, now it gives me this- `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`